# Laravel 5.2 eloquent compare date time to current data and time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to make a notification for the agents in my CRM.

I store the date and time they pick in my database and compare it to the current **data and time**.

> I have tried this:

```
$notification   = Main::select('id') -> whereRaw('Date(notification) = CurDate()') -> where('user_id', '=', $userid) -> get();
```

it works perfectly but compare only the current **date** with the saved **date**.

What I am looking for is to compare the current date and time with the stored date and time. If that time and date **match or passed** then do anything.

I don't want to use Carbon because I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Certainly the best reason not to learn something. Why not just `->where("notification", ">=", $date)` ?

Comment: @Blake i have tried this but the time is not working good! this is an example `2016-09-17 11:25:0` how i compare it with the current time or if it is passed?

Comment: `where("notification", "<=", date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))`

Comment: thank you!
you could make it as an answer

Comment: Updated with answer. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this instead:

```
$notification = Main::select('id')
                ->where("notification", "<=", date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
                ->get();
```